# SQL Server stored procedure parameter restrictions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there anyway to add a suffix to a parameter in a stored procedure?

I have a stored procedure that is inserts document names and numbers and the employees in my company can enter the document names/numbers to our database via our website, but for three clients of ours, they name their documents a specific way i.e. a normal entry for a name: "PDF1234-1" and for a number: "23410" but these clients name theirs like: "FED-PDF1234-1" for the name. They want to add a prefix code and there are 5 codes they want to use.

Now the issue is all of our clients use this so I cant change it just to suit them that's why I was thinking is it possible to add a suffix limit to a parameter? Like if the parameter that passes the document name is `@documentname` would I be able to add a restriction such as

```
IF clientid IN (1, 2, 3) 
   THEN have to have to have "FED" "ECX"" etc.?
```

Comment: What is the "this" all of your clients use -- can you not modify the *website* code or can you not modify the *stored procedure*? The former seems more likely given the structure of your question, but I'd like to know for sure anyway.

Comment: @JeroenMostert this as in the website and the process of entering document numbers and no I cant modify the website code as I only have access from the backend and I myself am not good with html and css, is this even possible? I cant think of a way to accommodate this via the stored procedure

Comment: Well, is the client ID you need to distinguish clients even passed to the stored procedure? That is, can you determine programmatically in the stored procedure if the prefix is to be added or not? Also, your question doesn't make it clear what you want to do: do you want to *add* a prefix in the database based on client ID, or verify/enforce that a particular prefix is being used? Would `@documentname` contain `FED-PDF1234-1` when called or `PDF1234-1`? Certainly, you can manipulate strings in T-SQL code (`SET @documentname = N'FED' + @documentname`), that's not the issue.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I apologize for not clarifiying earlier yes we pass through the clientid was well, I want to verify/enforce that if its those 3 clients that a particular set of prefix codes are used, Documentname would contain "FED-PDF1234-1" as opposed to "PDF1234-1", so would that statement work? I am wondering how would that be incorporated so I can use that for all 5 prefixes? would that work? and thank you so much for the help, I greatly appreciate it

Comment: Well, you're almost there in your hypothetical code -- you can check the format of the strings with `LIKE` and abort/signal an error to the website with `RAISERROR`. Something like `IF @clientid IN (1, 2, 3) AND (@documentname NOT LIKE 'FED-%' AND @documentname NOT LIKE 'ECX-%' AND...) BEGIN; RAISERROR('Missing prefix.', 11, 1); RETURN; END;`. You can easily invert this condition if you want to cover the cases where the prefix must *not* be there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it worked! thank you so much!

Comment: Consider posting the code you ultimately used as an answer and accepting it; the site can always use one more answered question!

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes of course I used this:

Comment: You can answer your own questions. Use the "Your Answer" text box below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JereonMostert stated I just did this

IF @ClientID = 45 AND ((@DocumentName like '%-FEX') 
                      or (@DocumentName like '%-AMX%'))
Then 
 Condition